# Solicitar ubicaciones de una web a un dispositivo android

Tags: android-studio

Estoy realizando una App con webservice en php, me pidieron controlar a usuarios por su dispositivo Android, ósea si en una pagina web solicito ver la ubicación del dispositivo la app me mandaría la información, no se por donde empezar si alguien me pudiera ayudar gracias. Los dispositivos Android tienen un ID único, como se puede acceder. Una opción seria que mi aplicación mande la ubicación del usuario regularmente en periodos de tiempo pero parece gasto de recursos lo que necesito es de una plataforma web realizar una petición y el dispositivo me devuelva la informacion

Comment: En el manifest debes agregar el permiso para usar la ubicación. Hay bastantes tutoriales.

Comment: gracias por responder, se como trabajar con ubicaciones lo que necesito es realizar una petición a un celular desde una web supongo que mi app tiene que estar trabajando en segundo plano. Ahora lo que no me queda claro es como puedo acceder al dispositivo Android en el caso de la computadores accedemos a su dirección ip publica y podemos acceder a ella en el caso de los dispositivos Android no se si tienen un ID único y si es así como puedo acceder a este. Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Cada dispositivo tiene un id único. Puedes almacenar ese id en la base de datos como lo hacen para enviar notificaciones push.